# Shell prompt displays .f>

Tags: shell, prompt

I am running SSH through this command:

`ssh <machine-name>`

But instead of seeing the machine name in the prompt, I see `.f>`.
Normally the prompt looks something like `machinename>`

Any ideas as to why the prompt displays as `.f>`  instead of `machinename>`?

Comment: Actually the command I am running is: "ssh <machinename>"

Comment: Use the edit link under your post. And check out the formatting options to highlight the commands vs prose.

Comment: Add to your post: your shell and its prompt or PS1 settings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running a BASH shell on the remote machine, the most probable cause is a bad `PS1` setting. To see what you're `PS1` is at the moment, simply type `echo $PS1` into the terminal. It might actually be `.f>`, in which case, you have your reason. If it is something else, not to worry, because it can be changed by simply exporting the `PS1` variable:
`export PS1="`*`prompt`*`"`
where *prompt* is the desired prompt. 
You said you usually see something along the lines of `machinename>`, you can do that by changing the value of `PS1` to `\h>`, which will display your hostname followed by a `>`. There are many other escape characters that you can utilize to create a more functional prompt, but this should fix your problem. To save that prompt, add the line `export PS1="\h> "` to your `.bashrc`.
For more information on `PS1`, go to the following sites:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/

Comment: One does not need to `export` the `PS1` variable.  One merely needs to set it.  Its value inside the shell process that is writing out the prompt is what matters, not whatever is exported by that shell to its children.